# updating all excel embedded links in word doc

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, updating

thanks nick i tried that, but ihad to specify the excel application for it to work as this is in word VBA. I also cut the code down so that it only changes links and odesnt up but its still slow. I cant understand this as when i only update the links using

```
Activedocument.fields.update
```

it is instantly finished. I know this is only updating and not changing the source but still the time difference is too big.

My full code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim OldFile As String
Dim xlsobj As Object
Dim xlsfile_chart As Object
Dim dlgSelectFile As FileDialog 'FileDialog object '
Dim thisField As Field
Dim selectedFile As Variant
'must be Variant to contain filepath of selected item
Dim newFile As Variant
Dim fieldCount As Integer '
Dim x As Long
On Error GoTo LinkError
'create FileDialog object as File Picker dialog box
Set dlgSelectFile = Application.FileDialog
(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With dlgSelectFile
.Filters.Clear 'clear filters
.Filters.Add "Microsoft Excel Files", "*.xls, *.xlsb, *.xlsm,  
*.xlsx" 'filter for only Excel files
'use Show method to display File Picker dialog box and return user's 
action
If .Show = -1 Then
 'step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection
 For Each selectedFile In .SelectedItems
   newFile = selectedFile 'gets new filepath
 Next selectedFile
 Else 'user clicked cancel
 Exit Sub
 End If
 End With
 Set dlgSelectFile = Nothing
'update fields



 Set xlsobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 xlsobj.Application.Visible = False
 Set xlsfile_chart = xlsobj.Application.Workbooks.Open(newFile,  
 ReadOnly   = True)

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With xlsobj.Application
 .calculation = xlcalculationmanual
 .enableevents = False
 End With



  fieldCount = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count
   For x = 1 To fieldCount
   With ActiveDocument.Fields(x)
   If .Type = 56 Then
  .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newFile
    End If
   End With
  Next x

  With xlsobj.Application
 .calculation = xlcalculationmanual
 .enableevents = True
 End With

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True



  MsgBox "Data has been sucessfully linked to report"

   'clean up
   xlsfile_chart.Close SaveChanges:=False
   Set xlsfile_chart = Nothing
   xlsobj.Quit
   Set xlsobj = Nothing


    Exit Sub
  LinkError:
  Select Case Err.Number
   Case 5391 'could not find associated Range Name
    MsgBox "Could not find the associated Excel Range Name " & _
   "for one or more links in this document. " & _
   "Please be sure that you have selected a valid " & _
   "Quote Submission input file.", vbCritical
    Case Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical
   End Select


   ' clean up
    Set xlsfile_chart = Nothing
     xlsobj.Quit
     Set xlsobj = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: the newfile in the code is just a filepath taken from a dialog box where the user picks the linking excel file so I think that parts fine. I think the loop here might be doing needless updates or something?

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating=False

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

        'Your code here.

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating=True
```

Comment: thanks nick I tried that and modified my code but its still slow. This is in word vba so i dnot know if thats a point or not. I added my full code above. If you could give me anymore advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well, If/then statements are generally slow-ish. So maybe figure out a way to replace those? There's a way you can do a workaround in your code with a boolean statement I think, and idk if that'll be MUCH faster, but maybe it will? check this out: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm